# Что означает данное выражение?

Tags: c++, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Помогите пожалуйста понять данный код.

```
//class
class EPS
{
  EPS() : a(0) {}
  explicit EPS(int l_val) : a(l_val) {}
  int getVal() { return a }
  bool drop(const EPS&l_eps, int l_point);
  int a;
};

//global
std::vector<EPS> tet;

//some func
bool func(const EPS &l_eps)
{
  return std::find_if(tet.begin(), tet.end(),
  [&l_eps](EPS& eps)
  { 
    return eps.drop(l_eps, eps.getVal());
  }) != tet.end();
}
```

Собственно что происходит в функции `func`? Что значит `[&l_eps](EPS &eps)`? По другому нельзя это написать?

Добавлено: 
Как перегрузить оператор функции отбросив использование лямбда функции?
Вот так правильно?
//class ESP

```
   bool operator()(ESP &eps)const
        {
            return eps.drop(*this ,eps.getVal());
        }
```

Comment: Данный код понимается так: обьект класса  EPS невозможно создать... Дальше говорить не о чем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это - *лямбда-выражение*. Т.е. функциональный объект, который служит предикатом при поиске `find_if`.

```
[&l_eps](EPS& eps)
{ 
    return eps.drop(l_eps, eps.getVal());
}
```

Это такая упрощенная форма записи для создания анонимного класса, в объекте которого хранится ссылка на `l_eps` и который в операторе `operator()(EPS&)` выполняет вот тот самый `drop`.

Конечно, это можно записать явно как функциональный объект или как функцию, работающую с глобальной переменной, но так - проще, красивее и понятнее (и не надо далеко бегать посмотреть, кто за предикат использован в `find_if`).

Примерно (не компилировал) так:

```
class Func
{
public:
    Func(EPS& l_eps):l_eps(l_eps){}
    bool operator()(EPS&eps)
    {
        return eps.drop(l_eps, eps.getVal());
    }

private:
    EPS& l_eps;
};

...

return std::find_if(tet.begin(), tet.end(), Func(l_eps));
```

Кстати, я бы рекомендовал не избегать `const` при объявлении de facto константных вещей...

Comment: А как мне перегрузить через оператор функции отбросив использование лямбда функции. Посмотрите как я сделал и скажите правильно или нет?

Comment: Нет, это не оператор в `EPS`, это создается отдельный класс-функтор... См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 4):

1. `[](){}` это объявление [лямбда-функции](https://habr.com/ru/post/66021/)
2. `[&l_eps]` - захват переменной l_eps по ссылке
3. `(EPS &eps)` - параметр функции ну и так далее

В func ищется в векторе tet нечто, что возвращает true об `eps.drop(l_eps, eps.getVal());`

Переписать то, конечно, можно. Только вот, кмк, сейчас вполне ок написано.

Comment: То есть у меня там переменная a объекта eps будет равнятся нулю?

Comment: Необязательно. Берётся то она из вектора tet по ссылке...

Comment: Тогда я не понял. Помогите мне написать оператор функции в классе EPS. bool operator() (EPS &l_e){ return l_e.drop(l_e, l_e.getVal());} Это неправильно?

Comment: Не совсем понятно какой нужен результат...

Comment: ну через объявление лямбда функции правильно все. А как мне сделать без лямбда функции? То есть перегрузив в классе оператор функции.

Comment: Не выйдет. find_if принимает в себя только указатель на функцию с одним параметром, а для запуска eps.drop нужно их два. В лямбду второй передаётся об захват окружения.

Comment: "Только вот, кмк, сейчас вполне ок написано "?  .. Нет сейчас написано с многими ошибками. Нет спецификаторов доступа( даже невозможно создать обьект),  геттер не  работает для константных обьектов(отсутствует const), после тела геттера есть точка с запятой, а класс заканчивается без точки с запятой. Не понятно смысль функции_члена drop(по ее обьявлению, она должна изменять свои данные, свой второй аргумет ... А значит невозможно работать с костантными итераторами в  std::find_if  вызывая для каждого обьекта этот метод. Так что  написано не  вполне ок, а вполне неграмотно...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я не стал бы придираться к демонстрационному коду. А то так можно дойти и до "нет инклуда вектора".

Comment: @Sheridan, а я и не придираюсь. Только в вопросе код такой, что ваши ответы не помогут,  по указанным причинам. Чтобы рассказывать о том что такое лямбда выражение и как работает(что и вы сделали) код вовсе  и не нужен, а если код демонстрирован, нужно рассказать, что он не будет  работать, если даже убрать ошибки компиляции. Я сторонник того, чтобы ТС знал что ему ждет с таким кодом